# Using Jekyll and Github pages

Tags: github, jekyll

I created a "jekyll new xx" site locally. When I run Jekyll serve it works very nicely.

Now, I create a new github repo and a branch gh-pages: https://github.com/pitosalas/deleteme

However when it is rendered as a github page it looks all wrong, like style sheets and other assets are missing.

### Update

Steven Perry: Thanks for your response, but I had a typo. I wanted to point to the github repo containing the Jekyll "input" files which are then regenerated into the stuff that is served to the browser. The extra slash in the CSS file is an excellent clue but it is in a file generated by Jekyll I think. I can't edit it directly I need to figure out how to get Jekyll to generate it correctly. Do you know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```htm
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/syntax.css">
<!--                         ^
                            /
       remove this slash ---
-->
```

[Example](http://github.com/svnpenn/bm/blob/3c4f5ad/_layouts/page.htm#L5)

For more info, your problem file is here

[`default.html`](http://github.com/pitosalas/deleteme/blob/gh-pages/_layouts/default.html)

Comment: thanks! Odd that in all the instructions about how to use jekyll with github pages this little detail/bug is not mentioned.